# $2^a+2^b=37k$ where $a(>1)$,$b(>1)$ and $ k$ are integers is not possible.

Tags: number-theory

I was trying do a problem I was stuck , the only remaining to  prove was that $2^a+2^b=37k$ where $a(>1),b(>1)$ and $k$ are integers is not possible.

Comment: $2^{18} + 1 = 37\cdot 7085$. Multiply by any power of $2$.

Comment: edit a and b must be greater than 1

Comment: @DanielFischer thnx..

Comment: Ah, well, maybe we can help you solve the problem in some other way?

Answer (score 9):

Using $2^{18} + 1 = 37 \cdot 7085$
you can simply take $a = 20$ and $b = 2$ for example and you get $$2^{20}+2^2 = 37\cdot(7085\cdot 4)$$

Any other multiple of two also works as a counter example.
The assertion is wrong.